# String index out of bounds? (Java, substring loop)

Tags: java, substring, while-loop

This program I'm making for a COSC course isn't compiling right, I keep getting the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2

at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1765)
 at VowelCount.main(VowelCount.java:13)

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelCount {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0, count = 0;
  String input, letter;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

  System.out.println ("Please enter a string: ");
  input = scan.nextLine();

  while (count <= input.length() ) {
   letter = input.substring(count, (count + 1));

   if (letter == "a") {
    a++; }
   if (letter == "e") {
    e++; }
   if (letter == "i") {
    i++; }
   if (letter == "o") {
    o++; }
   if (letter == "u") {
    u++; }

   count++;

  }
  System.out.println ("There are " + a + " a's.");
  System.out.println ("There are " + e + " e's.");
  System.out.println ("There are " + i + " i's.");
  System.out.println ("There are " + o + " o's.");
  System.out.println ("There are " + u + " u's.");
 }
}
```

To my knowledge this should work, but why doesn't it? Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You may need to take out the = in the line

```
while (count <= input.length() ) {
```

and make it

```
while (count < input.length() ) {
```

because it is causing the substring to read beyond the length of the string.

===============
But I'll add a few extra bits of advice even though its not asked for:

do not use == to compare strings, use

```
letter.equals("a")
```

instead. Or even better, try using

```
char c = input.charAt(count);
```

to get the current character then compare like this:

```
c == 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the equal sign should fix that.

`while (count < input.length()) {`

and since you want to get a single character, you should do this:

`substr(count,1)`

because the 2nd parameter is actually length, not index.

Comment: Alright, it compiles! But still doesn't output the right amounts. Test string "aeiou" results in 0, 0, 0, 0, 0..

Comment: Do not use == to compare strings as mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop condition should be `count < input.length`. Right now, the last iteration runs with `count == length`, so your `substring` call is given a start index after the last character in the string, which is illegal. These type of boundary errors are very common when writing such loops, so it's always good to double- and triple-check your loop conditions when you encounter a bug like this.

Also, comparing strings with the `==` operator usually won't do what you want. That compares whether or not the two variables reference the same object. Instead, you want to test `string1.equals(string2)`, which compares the contents of the two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with help from everyone, and especially Vincent. Thank you! Runs wonderfully.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0, count = 0;
        String input;
        char letter;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print ("Please enter a string: ");
        input = scan.nextLine();

        while (count < input.length() ) {
            letter = input.charAt (count);

            if (letter == 'a')
                a++; 
            if (letter == 'e') 
                e++; 
            if (letter == 'i') 
                i++; 
            if (letter == 'o') 
                o++; 
            if (letter == 'u') 
                u++; 

            count++;

        }
        System.out.println ("There are " + a + " a's.");
        System.out.println ("There are " + e + " e's.");
        System.out.println ("There are " + i + " i's.");
        System.out.println ("There are " + o + " o's.");
        System.out.println ("There are " + u + " u's.");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use a for loop to tidy it up even further: - for(int count = 0; count < input.length(); count++)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @WilQu did you read this question? it's the OP posting the working solution. how should this be a comment?

Comment: @meda I see this as a comment only saying that the other answers worked. It does not add anything to the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Before loop,try below

```
if(input.length()>0){
//you code
}
```