# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to count 'a's in the entered word in Java

Tags: java, stringindexoutofbounds

```
public class methods {
    public static int howMany(String word) {
        char character = 'a';
        int a = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<=word.length();i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i)==character) {
                a++;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(howMany("afdfaf"));
    }
}
```

code gives error.
please help.
I couldn't find where is the error.

Expected output:

```
2
```

Observed error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
```

The exception happens in this line:

```
    if (word.charAt(i)==character) {
```

Comment: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you're reading one character past the length of the word? Wouldn't have to guess if your question had included the error and the stacktrace.

Comment: Use for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { instead of your for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++) {

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen What should I do

Comment: Not very welcoming to downvote a newcomer...

Comment: @RudyVissers Aren't up, down, and close-votes supposed to be handed out based exclusively on the quality of the question itself? Should a bad question be up-voted because a user is new? If so, what other criteria should be taken into account when voting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String index out of bounds? (Java, substring loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569868/string-index-out-of-bounds-java-substring-loop). Search for more.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I didn't say 'upvoted'. I have written, 'downvoted'. I found that a bit harsh. My feeling is that asking good questions is a learning. When you start using SO, you could ask a few questions that do not reach the quality we want on the website.
The quality I want. But we can comment and ask for clarity/helping to rephrase/correcting the spelling. Even asking to close the question. I prefer comments to downvotes for new contributors. But this is subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line, you are exceeding the word length

Rewrite:

```
for (int i=0;i<=word.length();i++)
```

into

```
for (int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
```

Comment: What should i write